# Cómo utilizar cURL y PHP para modificar referer

Tags: php, curl, referer

Estoy intentando aprender a usar cURL con PHP para cambiar el referer de un sitio web.

Con el siguiente script esperaba lograr esto... pero parece que no funciona.

Lo que quiero es modificar el referer pero por lo que me estoy dando cuenta con cURL lo unico que hace es añadir una pagina dentro de otra, como si fuera un iFrame. Es esto lo que debe hacer? Hay alguna manera de cambiar el referer?

¿Alguna idea/sugerencia de dónde me estoy equivocando?

¿O sabes de algún tutorial que pueda ayudarme a resolver esto?

¡Gracias!

```
<?php
$host = "http://mysite.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Hola! Por qué dices que parece que no funciona? QUé esperabas? QUé pasó en su lugar? Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/498833/edit) la pregunta y cuéntanos qué esperas que pase cuando se ejecuta ese script.

Comment: @Alfabravo editado! Basicamente Lo que quiero es modificar el referer pero por lo que me estoy dando cuenta con cURL lo unico que hace es añadir una pagina dentro de otra, como si fuera un iFrame. Hay alguna manera de cambiar el referer?

Comment: Con este codigo que dejaste si cambia el referrer y podes elegir por cual.
[PHP - Referer redirect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857427/php-referer-redirect-script) Y con Javascript es mas Simple, podes mirar esto que te indican la parte que necesitas.. ( Usa javascript aunque diga que es phantom ) [Change Referrer](https://gist.github.com/liushooter/449394ebeac56980d68f)